# How to start different Timers

Tags: java, timer

I've build a application with JButtons for play and pause and 24 jtogglebuttons with this class:

```
public class TrackerButton extends JToggleButton {

public static Timer timer;
public static JToggleButton emptyToggleButton;
public static int counter;
public static HashMap<JToggleButton, Timer> buttonTimerMap = new HashMap<>();


public TrackerButton(String identifier) {
    emptyToggleButton = new JToggleButton("");
    emptyToggleButton.setVisible(false);
    emptyToggleButton.setFont(buttonFont);
    emptyToggleButton.setSelected(false);
    emptyToggleButton.addActionListener(selectListener);
    emptyToggleButton.setName(identifier);
    counter = 0;

    timer = new Timer(600, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            counter++;
            TimeCalculation timeCalculator = new TimeCalculation();
            for(JToggleButton toggleButton : buttonTimerMap.keySet()){
                if(toggleButton.isSelected()){
                    toggleButton.setText("<html>" + "<br>" + "Getrackte Zeit: " + timeCalculator.getCalculatedTime(counter) + "</html>");
                    break;
                }
            }


        }
    });
    buttonTimerMap.put(emptyToggleButton, timer);

}
```

In the other class, I've the start function:

```
TrackerButton.buttonTimerMap.get(localJToggleButton).start();
```

The problem is, that I don't understand, when this "actionperformed" is performed. As I've understood, as soon as start() is used.

my goal is, that I have 24 different jtoggle buttons and after selecting the button and click on the play button which uses start(), then it should rename the selected button all second, so that the user sees the timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#Timer-int-java.awt.event.ActionListener-):

> Creates a Timer and initializes both the initial delay and between-event delay to delay milliseconds.

In other words, the `ActionListener` will be first called approximately 600 ms after your `Timer` is `start`ed, and then every 600 ms after that.

Comment: And is the timer initializated by new Timer ... or by timer.start()?